# How do you create multiple layers of underbraces and overbraces?

Tags: underbrace, overbrace

I'm trying to create something like this:

[image]

But I just can't seem to figure out how to add that last bracket in the bottom without messing up the labels.

Here's my code:

```
\overbrace{
\underbrace{
\underbrace{0...}_v
\underbrace{...0}_y1
...}_{w_1'}
...1
}^{w_1}
\overbrace{\underbrace{0...}_v\underbrace{...0}_y1...1}^{w_2}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `tikz` package and `tikzmark,decorations.pathreplacing,calligraphy` libraries to mimic a drawing of brace at the desired location. It's hard to be 100% same with the original braces. There might be a better solution.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,decorations.pathreplacing,calligraphy}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\overbrace{\underbrace{\underbrace{0...}_v\underbrace{...0}_y1
...}_{w_1'}\tikzmark{s}
...1
}^{w_1}
\overbrace{\underbrace{0...}_v\underbrace{...0}_y1...1\tikzmark{e}}^{w_2}
\end{equation}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\draw [decoration={calligraphic brace,mirror,amplitude=5pt},decorate,line width=1.1pt] ([yshift=-16.5pt]pic cs:s) -- node[below=3pt]{\scriptsize$w_2'$} ([yshift=-16.5pt]pic cs:e);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

> Edit: Another solution using package `oubraces`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{oubraces}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\overunderbraces{&\br{3}{w_1}&\br{1}{w_2}}%
{&\underbrace{0...}_v\underbrace{...0}_y1...&~&...1&\underbrace{0...}_v\underbrace{...0}_y1...1}%
{&\br{1}{w_1'}&&\br{2}{w_2'}}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works, but I'm really trying to find the "right" way.

Comment: @student I add another solution.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a solution with `{NiceArray}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\arraycolsep}{1pt}
$\begin{NiceArray}{ccccccc}[cell-space-limits=5pt]
\underbrace{0 \dots }_{v} 
& \underbrace{\dots 0}_{y}
& 1 \dots 
& \dots 1
& \underbrace{0 \dots}_{v}
& \underbrace{\dots 0}_{y}
& 1 \dots 1 
\CodeAfter
  \UnderBrace[right-shorten]{1-1}{1-3}{\scriptstyle w_1'}
  \UnderBrace[left-shorten]{1-4}{1-7}{\scriptstyle w_2'}
  \OverBrace[right-shorten]{1-1}{1-4}{\scriptstyle w_1}
  \OverBrace[left-shorten]{1-5}{1-7}{\scriptstyle w_2}
\end{NiceArray}$

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]